# How can I fix Networking, Wi-Fi and Ethernet, not being available after update?

Tags: networking

After updating the OS today and rebooting, the wifi and ethernet has stopped working. Opening Network in the control panel gives me the error "The system network services are not compatible with this version".

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem. The above sollution seemed to get the icon back in the top right of screen, but nothing works in it

Comment: Mine worked just fine after following Lewis' instructions

Comment: @Spankalish Maybe try rebooting, mine brought all the connection profiles right back though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Ubuntu proposed repository recently released version 3.2.21-1ubuntu1 of several libnl* packages. There currently break the networking manager in elementary OS Freya.

#### Step 1. Download the architecture appropriate files for these three packages.

- [libnl-3-200](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libnl-3-200)
- [libnl-genl-3-200](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libnl-genl-3-200)
- [libnl-route-3-200](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libnl-route-3-200)

#### Step 2. Downgrade the Packages and Restart the Service

```
sudo dpkg -i libnl-*.deb;
sudo service network-manager restart
```

#### Step 3. Make sure it doesn't happen again.

Uncheck the `proposed` repository from your update settings. Sometimes these checkboxes don't work, since it is older Ubuntu software, so comment out the lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Which lines should be commented out Lewis?

Comment: @Gabriel Any that contain the word "proposed", probably towards the end.