# the system network services are not compatible with this version - permanent fix

Tags: updates, networking

I recently ran into the same Problem as [Louis Kuan](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4183/how-can-i-fix-networking-wi-fi-and-ethernet-not-being-available-after-update)

The fix from Lewis Goddard actually helped to get me connected again, thank you for that. Since i have to few reputation i am not allowed to comment on the Answer so I am forced to ask this way (sry for that):

Is there already any information about who exactly is affected by this mal update?

what exactly are the 3 mentioned packages:

- libnl-3-200
- libnl-genl-3-200
- libnl-route-3-200

I noticed, that my internet connection is a bit slower, than before the fix.

Since i had to comment out certain lines in the 
/etc/apt/sources.list file, i wont be getting any other updates from those   sources as well, right? So when can I expect an official update, that fixes this problem for good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update is currently in the "proposed" repository, which is used for testing updates. I think it is relatively safe to say that this specific one won't be making it into "main" anytime soon. Once another testing version is released, it will stop your network breaking from that repository, although I would never class "proposed" as "safe".

`libnl` is described as a "library for dealing with netlink sockets" at the [Ubuntu Package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libnl-3-200) site.
`genl` is a "library for dealing with netlink sockets - generic netlink" and `route` is a "library for dealing with netlink sockets - route interface".