# incompatible network problem elementary os 0.3.2 in my hp 450 notebook

Tags: networking

hello equipment elementary os, I am writing to know if there is a solution to my problem of network support, for that matter, yesterday make an update Freya software version 0.3.2 (64 bits, and is that when I go to start a connection Internet me a notice appears that says: "network services system are not compatible with this version" there is the possibility to fix that ?..

characteristics of my Ethernet card:

Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller

characteristics of my wireless network card:

802.11bgn Ralink RT3290 Wi-Fi Adapter

I hope your prompt response.

Comment: same problem here any updates?

Comment: @EngMahmoud See this duplicate http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4183/how-can-i-fix-networking-wi-fi-and-ethernet-not-being-available-after-update

Comment: oh , well and my problem was solved I saw another question in this forum and I followed the solution worked well .