# Avoid no network issue

Tags: networking, updates

As explained here [How can I fix Networking, Wi-Fi and Ethernet, not being available after update?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4183/how-can-i-fix-networking-wi-fi-and-ethernet-not-being-available-after-update) there is a regression bug that will cause some systems to lose network entirely.

Lewis' [excellent answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/4184/9) solves the issue, but after applying it I am immediately requested by the system to upgrade the downgraded libraries:

[image]

As far as I can tell, I have the *Poposed* repository[*] deselected:

[image]

Lewis says to "so comment out the lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list`", but I'm not sure which lines he is referring to.

---

[*]: I actually have **all of the repositories** in the *Updates* tab deselected. Is this how they should show?

Comment: I have that update available on my PC.Should I update

Comment: I ran it.Internet is working correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, quoting [this awesome answer on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/727462/141980), you have to mark the packages on hold:

```
sudo apt-mark hold libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 libnl-route-3-200
```

That worked for me really great