# How to downgrade libnl packages to fix network manager?

Tags: networking

In May my elementary OS network stopped working. I cannot connect to wifi or Ethernet. It seems the last update caused the network problem. Looking for the solution I came across this [How can I fix Networking, Wi-Fi and Ethernet, not being available after update?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4183/how-can-i-fix-networking-wi-fi-and-ethernet-not-being-available-after-update) 
I want to fix my network issues but I am having trouble understanding Step 2: Downgrade the Packages and Restart the Service.

I am still very new using non-windows/OSX operating systems such as linux. Can somebody explain to how exactly to downgrade the libnl packages? I have downloaded and saved the 3 libnl packages (from the link above) in my documents folder in elementary OS. I have tried to run `sudo dpkg -i libnl-*deb` command in terminal then I'm prompted to enter my password. I enter my password and I receive this error.

```
> dpkg: error processing archive libnl-*deb (--intall):
>  cannot access archive: No such file or directory 
> Errors were encountered while processing: 
>  libnl-*deb
```

I am not entirely sure what I'm suppose to do. Can somebody help me out with a simple noob step-by-step guide. I really like using elementary OS but I can't seem to figure this out. Help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try disabling **Secure Boot** in the BIOS if you have such a setting. My Braodcom wireless won't work anymore after software updates and with secure boot enabled.

Answer (score 0):

All the libnl packages are here.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libnl&searchon=names

If you're using eOS Freya, then that would be the Trusty version for Ubuntu.

Which version do you already have and which ones do you need?