# Wired and Wireless issue

Tags: system, wifi, networking, ethernet

On Live CD everything works well.

But after installation and several system updates via `AppCenter` `Wireless` has become unstable (drops connection) and `Wired` doesn't work although I returned to `4.4.0-38-generic` kernel.

I wonder that how can I get worked my Elementary OS like Elementary OS Live?

I'm struggled with this issue for days.

I would be appreciated for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Hi out if the blue its difficult to give help here.

1. Would you please run the commad
   `ifconfig` in the terminal and look in the output for en0 for example to see if the wired connection works.
2. Theres another thread with this issue maybe it helps:
   [How can I fix Networking, Wi-Fi and Ethernet, not being available after update?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4183/how-can-i-fix-networking-wi-fi-and-ethernet-not-being-available-after-update)
3. For more details on Network configuration heres a guide from Ubuntu:
   [Ubuntu - Network Configuration](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html)

Comment: I thank you very much!  These 3 clauses don't work for me. However thank you anyway...