# Wi-Fi doesnt work after update

Tags: updates, wifi, networking

My wi-fi stopped working. I used to have this problem from time to time and `service network-manager restart` was always enough to fix it, but after system update the wi-fi doesn't work at all even after reboot.

The network manager doesn't see any posible wi-fi connections.

I tried this to repair it: [How can I fix Networking, Wi-Fi and Ethernet, not being available after update?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4183/how-can-i-fix-networking-wi-fi-and-ethernet-not-being-available-after-update?newreg=1fc8b0f58f994b369fe64a9666105133) but it didn't help. I assume it is similar problem, but the solution is for older versions.
Can you pleas help me to repair my wi-fi again? The internet connection via ethernet works fine.

Comment: Are you going through a VPN?

Comment: No, I am not. Just trying to connect to my home wifi.

Answer (score 2):

Please go to AppCenter([appcenter](/questions/tagged/appcenter)) over an Ethernet connection and click on the installed tab. If you see **bcmwl-kernel-source**, install it by clicking on <kbd>free</kbd>. Your WiFi([wifi](/questions/tagged/wifi)) should be working again.